# wordpress 4.9.5: working to upload images, but fail to be displayed under media and feature

Tags: php, wordpress

I upgraded my wp from 4.9.* to latest 4.9.5. then the function of uploading images is working well , all of them will go to the folder wp-content/uploads,  I can also directly open the photo via pasting its http url to browser address bar.

The problems like below:

**1. all uploaded photos can NOT be displayed under media:**

media page:
[image]

add media page:
[image]

**2 all uploaded photos can NOT be added as feature picture:**
[image]

**3. all articles which already has feature picture can NOT show their own feature picture under front list page:**

[image]

I tried to fix this issue , but all **failed**, like below:

1. reinstall all plugins or reinstall the whole wordpress via manually downloading wordpress 4.9.5
2. disabled all plugins
3. add the code: define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );
4. change the uploads folder as 777

please help if I have a new solution ?

PS: I am using google cloud and ubunutu 17.10. the site works well for  months before few days.

Comment: maybe try this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/213220/128983) and see if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally! I found out the solutinon:  that is because my database has some problem, and I used the command "myisamchk" to fix it !

just follow below steps:

```html
sudo service mysql stop
sudo myisamchk -r -v -f /var/lib/mysql/{your-database-name}/{your-table-name}
sudo service mysql start
```